# How to track and see crashes of Flutter iOS after its distribution to others

Tags: ios, flutter, crashlytics, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I have released my app to **TestFlight** and one of users said that app is not working on his phone, but on other devices it's working.

So how can I see/track the reason of this crash. What kind of SDKs or crashlytics I can add to get datas about crashes and reasons of them?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/)

Following this Flutter official [tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/maintenance/error-reporting).

It works on all platforms.